# MSSQL and JDBC read DBCC USEROPTIONS

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I am trying to read some of the attributes returned by following command

```
DBCC USEROPTIONS
```

How to use following command in JDBC?

```
    List<ResultVO> list = getJdbcTemplate().query(sql, new ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper<ResultVO>() {
        @Override
        public ResultVO mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNumber) throws SQLException {
            System.out.println(rowNumber);
            ResultVO v = new ResultVO();
            v.setSetOption(rs.getString(0));
            v.setValue(rs.getString(1));
            //--
            return v;
        }
    }, (List<String>) null);
```

It throws exception as follows:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [SELECT DBCC USEROPTIONS]; The index 1 is out of range.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 1 is out of range.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:106)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first line of the error message indicates that your code tried to execute the SQL statement

```sql
SELECT DBCC USEROPTIONS
```

but that is not valid T-SQL syntax. The T-SQL statement

```sql
DBCC USEROPTIONS
```

does return a valid ResultSet, as illustrated by the following vanilla JDBC code:

```java
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl)) {
    try (
            Statement s = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("DBCC USEROPTIONS")) {
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        for (int i = 1; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            System.out.printf("[%s]: %s%n", rsmd.getColumnName(i), rsmd.getColumnTypeName(i));
        }
        System.out.println();
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2));
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```

which produces

```
[Set Option]: nvarchar
[Value]: nvarchar

textsize: -1
language: us_english
dateformat: mdy
datefirst: 7
lock_timeout: -1
quoted_identifier: SET
ansi_null_dflt_on: SET
ansi_warnings: SET
ansi_padding: SET
ansi_nulls: SET
concat_null_yields_null: SET
isolation level: read committed
```

It looks like you need to adjust your Spring JDBC code to just execute `DBCC USEROPTIONS`.